# Not able to render external DB data on admin tab

Tags: mysql, silverstripe

I am trying to to show external database data onto custom admin tab but getting error.Can some one help me to resolve this . I am able to fetch data from external DB but when i pass it to the GridField it gives me this error.

#### Error###

"get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given"

and here is my code

```
public function getList() {
    
    $externalDB = $object = Injector::inst ()->create ( 'ExternalDatabase' );
    $results = $externalDB->query ( 'SELECT "Course" FROM "Courses"' );
    $list = ArrayList::create ();
    foreach ( $results as $row ) {
        $list->push  ( $row ) ;
    }
    
    return $list;
}
```

I have ExternalDatabase Class which resolve my query and return result.

Comment: Show your code as you're passing data to the GridField.

Comment: WHERE does the error occur? File and line number shows you where the error occurs, the backtrace where the error might be caused...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing the row directly, try doing

`$list->push(ArrayData::create($row));`

Comment: ***Missing argument 1 for ArrayData::__construct()***

now getting this error after applying your solution